# Query row where column condition = 'x' only after a certain corresponding column condition = 'y' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

apologies in advance if I'm missing critical information, I'm very new to this.

I have a massive database of devices, receivers, and corresponding value that counts up one as messages are received.

For example, here is my original **table of data**:

```
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
|received_time          |receiver|device |message_type| value | 
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+                                          
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.850 | R1     |     D1|      2     |   1   |
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.853 | R1     |     D1|      1     |  NULL | 
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.947 | R1     |     D1|      2     |   1   |
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.957 | R1     |     D1|      1     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.060 | R2     |     D1|      2     |   1   | 
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.067 | R3     |     D1|      2     |   1   |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.073 | R3     |     D1|      1     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.170 | R4     |     D2|      1     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.283 | R5     |     D2|      2     |   0   |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.287 | R5     |     D2|      1     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:55:00.000 | R1     |     D2|      5     |  NULL |  
|2019-07-17 7:55:01.400 | R1     |     D2|      2     |   A   |
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+

and so on...
```

**OBJECTIVE**

My objective is to query for the corresponding value only where a specific `message_type` is listed. The problem is, this value is on a different row. This could be `message_type = '5'`, or `message_type = '1'` (whatever I'm currently looking for). The problem is, the only way I can think of to do this is by ordering by received_time but within a period of x seconds after the initial `message_type` condition has been met, however in some cases the '2' comes before the corresponding '1' `message_type`.

I have already tried different variations of the `GROUP BY` function, but this has been very confusing and I'm not sure where to go from here.

**Attempt #1** - Not good

```
SELECT received_time, receiver, device, message_type, value,
    CASE
        WHEN message_type = '5' THEN --Select corresponding value 
                                     --where message_type = '2'
    END 
FROM table;
```

**Attempt #2** - closer to what I'm trying to do

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE message_type = '5' 
        SELECT * FROM my_table
            WHERE
                received_time BETWEEN (received_time - 3 seconds) 
                and (received_time + 3 seconds)
                and (device = device) --order by for each device?
                and (message_type = '5' or message_type = '2')
```

My expected table should look this if I want to search for message_type = 5:

```
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
|received_time          |receiver|device |message_type| value | 
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+                                          
|2019-07-17 7:55:00.000 | R1     |     D2|      5     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:55:01.400 | R1     |     D2|      2     |   A   | 
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
```

But expected table should look this if I want to search for message_type = 1:

```
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
|received_time          |receiver|device |message_type| value | 
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+                                          
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.850 | R1     |     D1|      2     |   1   |
|2019-07-17 7:50:14.853 | R1     |     D1|      1     |  NULL | 
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.170 | R4     |     D2|      1     |  NULL |
|2019-07-17 7:50:15.283 | R5     |     D2|      2     |   0   |
+-----------------------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
```

This is a very tricky question to ask, and hard to explain.
Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `unit_type` or `message_type`?

Comment: my apologies, it should be message_type. I'll edit it. [NOW FIXED]

Comment: Are you looking for the row with message_type = 5 and all other rows that inserted after that row?

Comment: Yes sort of. I'm looking for rows where message_type =2 corresponds with message_type = 5, where device is the same AND within the same approximate time frame (within ~6 seconds). The value I want is unfortunately always where message_type = 2.

Comment: mkRabbani, a few issues come up with this: For one, sometimes a message_type = 2 comes before a message_type = 5. The important part is that device is the same and within the same time frame (usually within milliseconds apart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem is that you need that for each message_type 1 or 5 find the corresponding message_type 2 and get the value, with the consideration that the type 2 could be before and after the type 1 or 5. The solution I am proposing here considers that the corresponding type 2 is the one **closest** to the original message (type 1 or 5).

I do this in 2 steps:

1. Calculate which type 2 is closest to the one I want to find:

   select  t2.receiver,
               t2.device,
               t2.received_time,
               MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, t.received_time, t2.received_time))) AS closest_received_time
       INTO #tmpClosest
       from my_table as t 
           inner join my_table as t2 ON t.receiver = t2.receiver and t.device = t2.device
       where t.message_type = 2
         AND t2.message_type = 1 --define here the type for the main message (1 or 5)
       GROUP BY  t2.receiver, t2.device, t2.received_time
2. With this temp table then you can retrieve the value for the corresponding one

   SELECT tc.receiver,
           tc.device,
           tc.received_time,
           t.value
   FROM #tmpClosest AS tc
       INNER JOIN my_table AS t ON t.receiver = tc.receiver AND t.device = tc.device
   WHERE tc.closest_received_time = ABS(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, t.received_time, tc.received_time))

Comment: cte6, you articulated my problem very well. You're exactly correct. I will try to tackle it now with your advice. Thanks so much. I'll come back after I have tried it to update with my results.

Comment: Yes, I just verified everything. This method works extremely well and is just what I was looking for.